# How to bind Window background to a theme's Window background color?

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, xaml, themes

How can I bind the default Window background color of the theme to a Window background?

I've tried the following:

```
<Window x:Class="Shell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Shell" 
    Height="300" 
    Width="300" 
    Background="{DynamicResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
    >
```

But the background color renders as black and that does not seem right when using the Luna theme. Using the Luna theme I would expect the beige/brownish color often found in Windows XP.

**UPDATE:** After reading your answers, playing with [StyleSnooper](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2007/01/02/wpf-tools-stylesnooper/) and thinking some more about this I've come to the following conclusion:

The Window will use SystemColors.WindowBrush as its background color by default. This color is white in most themes i've tried and that is probably OK. I believe white is also the Window background color in WinForms. However, the default Form background color in WinForms is not Window background but Control. So, if I want that color I have use `SystemColors.ControlBrush` as pointed out by [Lucas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24231/lucas).

At one point I was trying to achieve the brownish/beige Control color of WinForms on Windows XP. This is probably not possible on Windows Vista since Control color on Vista is kind of gray. Running a WinForms application on Windows Vista will not render it as beige/brownish, but gray. In this case I guess we have to apply our own custom styles to achieve the "original" Windows XP look on Vista.

Thanks everyone for helping me sort this out!

Comment: Did You solve this?  I'd like to change the background on a trigger.

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1955583/492

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does applying a theme actually override the system brushes as I would expect? If so, you should be able to do this:

```
<Window ...
    Background="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrush}
    ...>
```

**Edit**

As per Manga's comment, you'll probably want to use SystemColors.ControlBrush to achieve the desired effect, because WindowBrush on most systems is white. ControlBrush is the "off-white" colour you're seeing on Windows XP.

Comment: i get white brackground from this, but following that suggestion, you could try `SystemColors.ControlBrush`, `SystemColors.ControlDarkBrush`, etc

Comment: +1 for pointing me in the right direction. I would however like to accept an answer where the SystemColors.ControlBrush is applied to the Background like Lucas suggest. On your marks...

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought that simply leaving the `Background` property unset on your `Window` element would achieve this.  The whole point of a theme is that it effects the default appearance of visual elements such as your `Window`.

**EDIT** You might look at [StyleSnooper](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2007/01/02/wpf-tools-stylesnooper/) -- it will let you view the default template for a control (such as Window).  You should be able to determine what property it is binding to for each theme.

Comment: Applying the Luna theme and leaving the Background property of my Window unset gives me a white background. I would expected a beige/brownish background as you would get in WinForms on Windows XP or a grayish background as you get in WinForms on Vista. If white background is the correct behavior maybe I need to rephrase my question.

Comment: +1 for making me think differently about this and pointing me to StyleSnooper!